# How do you identify an element in a tuple within an array

Tags: python, tuples

Main question: How do you identify an element within a tuple within an array? Example:

```
[(1,2),(1,4),(5,6),(4,8)]
```

Sub question: I wanted to isolate the parent nodes of each tuple which had no other parents (I wanted to isolate 1 and 5 in the example above.)

I tried to iterate through the first element of each tuple in the array so something like

```
for i in array
```

Comment: What is parent node?

Comment: Please ask a single question. You can always ask two questions if you wanted to know two different things.

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `[tup[0] for tup in array]`

Comment: What do you mean by "had no other parents"?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Using the term parent node will confuse a lot of people for something as simple as the first element. Please avoid it.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation: [Tuples and sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Answer (score 3):

Simply loop through each array item (i.e tuple), and fetch the first element.

```
for item in arr:
    do_something_with (item[0])
```

Parent node is not right term to use here. This might suit the scenario you want to solve in that case, mention the details. e.g. Are you considering edges in a tree in the array? Otherwise you'd confuse people by using such words.

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack the tuples as you iterate through the list:

```
for parent, _ in array:
    print(parent)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use inverse [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function to isolate first and second elements

```
>>> result = list(zip(*[(1,2),(1,4),(5,6),(4,8)]))
>>> result
>>> [(1, 1, 5, 4), (2, 4, 6, 8)]
```

Now the parent nodes are:

```
>>> result[0]
>>> (1, 1, 5, 4)
```

For the second part check which parent node element(s) are not in second element of tuple:

```
>>> [r for r in result[0] if r not in result[1]]
>>> [1, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the first element or as you call it the parent node as follows-

```
array =  [(1,2),(1,4),(5,6),(4,8)]
for tuple_ in array:
    print(tuple_[0])
    # Do other stuff with the parent element which is tuple_[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list from the array using list comprehension;

```
array =  [(1,2),(1,4),(5,6),(4,8)]
print([x[0] for x in array])
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the language as python

```
k= [(1,2),(1,4),(5,6),(4,8)]
for x in k:
    print(x[0])
```